# ROS Answers SE migration: built robot

Tags: ros, arduino, kinect, sensor

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hai friends

iam trying to built a robot like eddie. im have following things
kinect, arduino , ultrasonic sensors 4 n.o , stepper motor(im not having encoder for dc motor or i should buy it)

i want to implement touch screen & joystick control, obstacle avoidance and "follow me" application.

if any body done similar work, give the links to download the code ,hardware assembly instruction , kinect caliberation and its code

thank you in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/56442/built-robot/) by [vikirobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/3978/vikirobot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2013-02-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would look closely at TurtleBot, much of the code for eddie is a port from TurtleBot.

http://www.ros.org/wiki/TurtleBot

---

Originally posted by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) with karma: 8372 on 2013-02-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jon Stephan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2281/jon-stephan/) on 2013-03-02**:
This link is broken.  Should it be http://ros.org/wiki/Robots/TurtleBot ?